# Laravel Backpack - Upload multiple in PageTemplate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, upload, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to upload multiple images on page edit form. In my **PageTemplates.php** I have:

```
$this->crud->addField([ 
    'name' => 'images',
    'label' => 'Fotos',
    'type' => 'upload_multiple',
    'upload' => true,
    'disk' => 'uploads',
    'hint' => 'Some hint text.',
    'fake' => true
]);
```

In my **Page model** I have:

```
public function setImagessAttribute($value)
{
    $attribute_name = "images";
    $disk = "uploads";
    $destination_path = "images/pages";

    $this->uploadMultipleFilesToDisk($value, $attribute_name, $disk, $destination_path);
}
```

In my **$disks** array in **config/filesystems.php** I have:

```
'uploads' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => public_path('uploads'),
],
```

But when I try to save the page I have 2 problems:

- Images aren't saved in folder (folder is writeable!)
- Not saved in database

In my database **extras field** for that page I get:

```
"images":[  
  {  

  },
  {  

  }
],
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It worked after doing the following:

- Add images field to pages table
- Add 'images' to `$fillable` in Page model
- Remove `'fake' => true` from PageTemplates.php